# Difference calling function inside onPress{}

Tags: react-native

What's de difference between calling a function like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress{function()}> </TouchableOpacity>
```

Or call it like

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress{() => function()}> </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: the second one is function within a function

Comment: But what changes from one to another? Which one should I use?

Comment: You should use second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line, as soon as the component is rendered, the function() will get called, which is not the proper way. If you want to run a function like that, then make use of the `useEffect` hook.

`<TouchableOpacity onPress{function()}> </TouchableOpacity>`

On the other hand in the following case, the  `following()` will only get executed once the `TouchableOpacity` component is pressed.

`<TouchableOpacity onPress{() => function()}> </TouchableOpacity>`